# MySQL: slave log sequence number is in the future (but master is fine)

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

I have a master server replicating to a slave. I'm being plagued by this error message on the slave:

```
2021-07-01 08:39:25 7f04881ee700 InnoDB: Error: page 194 log sequence number 142640849934
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 58431447820.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
```

The master server does not report this error in the error log, and everything seems to be working. At first I thought it was because of clock drift, so I installed NTP on master and slave and recreated the slave from scratch following [these instructions](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html). However, it is still happening - why is that, when the systems are kept in sync and the slave is freshly created? In fact, what does the error actually mean?

***Edit:*** I should have stated explicitly that his problem occurs on the slave immediately after setting up the slave.

The way I set up the slave is described in [Percona's instructions](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html):

- Take a backup with innobackupex
- Run innobackupex with `--apply-log`
- Copy to mysql's data directory on slave server
- set up replication

I didn't think about checking whether the problem happens immediately after starting mysql on the slave or only after I start replication.

Comment: I've seen this before when I removed the ib_logfile files when trying to fix a database corruption (on a non live system). In the end I wiped out the whole database and started from scratch as it seemed the only way to stop the errors.

Comment: Removing ib_logfile is only an option if following the explicit documentation in the official documentation and may not even help. Creating a fresh slave sounds like the most time and reliability productive way to rectify this.